# TypeORM select all rows but limit 25

Tags: node.js, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

`CandidateEntity`

```
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class CandidateEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;

    @OneToOne(() => CandidateEmployeeInfoEntity, employeeInfo => employeeInfo.candidate)
    public employeeInfo: CandidateEmployeeInfoEntity;
}
```

`EmployeeInfoEntity`

```
@Entity({ name: 'candidates_employee_infos' })
export class CandidateEmployeeInfoEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;

    @Column({ type: 'bool', nullable: false })
    public relocation: boolean;

    @Column({ type: 'text', nullable: true })
    public softSkills: string;

    @OneToOne(() => CandidateEntity, candidate => candidate.employeeInfo)
    public candidate: CandidateEntity;

    @Column({ type: 'integer' })
    public candidateId: number;
}
```

I create query to select first 25 rows from 104 rows in database

```
const {
    perPage = 25,
    page = 1,
} = params;
const skip = (perPage * page) - perPage;

let candidatesQuery = this.candidateRepository.createQueryBuilder('candidates');
candidatesQuery = candidatesQuery.leftJoinAndSelect(`candidates.employeeInfo`, 'employeeInfo'); // problem in this relation
candidatesQuery = candidatesQuery.skip(skip);
candidatesQuery = candidatesQuery.take(perPage);

const { entities, raw } = await candidatesQuery.getRawAndEntities();
const count = await candidatesQuery.getCount();

console.log(entities.length) // 104 rows
console.log(raw.length) // 104 rows
console.log(count) // 104 rows
```

Output sql query when typeorm return not correct results

first query

```
SELECT DISTINCT "distinctAlias"."candidates_id" as "ids_candidates_id" FROM (SELECT "candidates"."id" AS "candidates_id", "candidates"."uuid" AS "candidates_uuid", "candidates"."role" AS "candidates_role", "candidates"."first_name" AS "candidates_first_name", "candidates"."last_name" AS "candidates_last_name", "candidates"."email" AS "candidates_email", "candidates"."phone" AS "candidates_phone", "candidates"."phone_prefix" AS "candidates_phone_prefix", "candidates"."country_id" AS "candidates_country_id", "candidates"."city_id" AS "candidates_city_id", "candidates"."avatar" AS "candidates_avatar", "candidates"."confirmed_at" AS "candidates_confirmed_at", "candidates"."is_generated" AS "candidates_is_generated", "candidates"."created_at" AS "candidates_created_at", "candidates"."birthday" AS "candidates_birthday", "candidates"."type" AS "candidates_type", "employeeInfo"."id" AS "employeeInfo_id", "employeeInfo"."hourly_rate_from" AS "employeeInfo_hourly_rate_from", "employeeInfo"."hourly_rate_to" AS "employeeInfo_hourly_rate_to", "employeeInfo"."hourly_rate_currency" AS "employeeInfo_hourly_rate_currency", "employeeInfo"."salary_rate_from" AS "employeeInfo_salary_rate_from", "employeeInfo"."salary_rate_to" AS "employeeInfo_salary_rate_to", "employeeInfo"."salary_rate_currency" AS "employeeInfo_salary_rate_currency", "employeeInfo"."relocation" AS "employeeInfo_relocation", "employeeInfo"."soft_skills" AS "employeeInfo_soft_skills", "employeeInfo"."candidate_id" AS "employeeInfo_candidate_id" FROM "users" "candidates" LEFT JOIN "candidates_employee_infos" "employeeInfo" ON "employeeInfo"."candidate_id"="candidates"."id" WHERE  "candidates"."type" IN ($1)) "distinctAlias" ORDER BY "candidates_id" ASC LIMIT 25
```

second query

```
SELECT "candidates"."id" AS "candidates_id", "candidates"."uuid" AS "candidates_uuid", "candidates"."role" AS "candidates_role", "candidates"."first_name" AS "candidates_first_name", "candidates"."last_name" AS "candidates_last_name", "candidates"."email" AS "candidates_email", "candidates"."phone" AS "candidates_phone", "candidates"."phone_prefix" AS "candidates_phone_prefix", "candidates"."country_id" AS "candidates_country_id", "candidates"."city_id" AS "candidates_city_id", "candidates"."avatar" AS "candidates_avatar", "candidates"."confirmed_at" AS "candidates_confirmed_at", "candidates"."is_generated" AS "candidates_is_generated", "candidates"."created_at" AS "candidates_created_at", "candidates"."birthday" AS "candidates_birthday", "candidates"."type" AS "candidates_type", "employeeInfo"."id" AS "employeeInfo_id", "employeeInfo"."hourly_rate_from" AS "employeeInfo_hourly_rate_from", "employeeInfo"."hourly_rate_to" AS "employeeInfo_hourly_rate_to", "employeeInfo"."hourly_rate_currency" AS "employeeInfo_hourly_rate_currency", "employeeInfo"."salary_rate_from" AS "employeeInfo_salary_rate_from", "employeeInfo"."salary_rate_to" AS "employeeInfo_salary_rate_to", "employeeInfo"."salary_rate_currency" AS "employeeInfo_salary_rate_currency", "employeeInfo"."relocation" AS "employeeInfo_relocation", "employeeInfo"."soft_skills" AS "employeeInfo_soft_skills", "employeeInfo"."candidate_id" AS "employeeInfo_candidate_id" FROM "users" "candidates" LEFT JOIN "candidates_employee_infos" "employeeInfo" ON "employeeInfo"."candidate_id"="candidates"."id" WHERE  "candidates"."type" IN ($1)
```

third query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT("candidates"."id")) as "cnt" FROM "users" "candidates" LEFT JOIN "candidates_employee_infos" "employeeInfo" ON "employeeInfo"."candidate_id"="candidates"."id" WHERE  "candidates"."type" IN ($1)
```

When I remove load relation `employeeInfo`.
This line
`candidatesQuery = candidatesQuery.leftJoinAndSelect('candidates.employeeInfo', 'employeeInfo');`

TypeORM return 25 rows

```
console.log(entities.length) // 25 rows
console.log(raw.length) // 25 rows
console.log(count) // 104 rows
```

Why ? And how to fix this problem ?

Comment: What I do when I have issues with typeorm is getting the sql query and see what it does exactly. So could you provide the getSql?

Comment: @SoftwarePerson I updated question, added sql

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you use Leftjoin typeorm doesn't add the LIMIT to its query.

From the creator of TypeORM:

> take and skip functionality does not work with raw data since its internal ORM functionality
>   https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1768

So to fix it there are two options:

1. If you want typeORM to do it for you, you should use getMany, instead of raw
2. If you want raw results you should can use `.offset` and `.limit` instead of `.skip`, `.take`. Since `.offset` and `.limit` will change the SQL query.

**Note**: it is a good idea to order by something when you are implementing pagination

Comment: using `offset` instead of `skip` worked for me while using query builder

Answer (score 6):

You can use take and skip with repository pattern:

```
const {
    perPage = 25,
    page = 1,
} = params;
const skip = (perPage * page) - perPage;

const candidates = await this.candidateRepository.find({
    relations: ['employeeInfo'],
    take: perPage,
    skip,
});
```

> also for pagination purpose I recommend to use findAndCount

```
const { perPage = 20, page = 1 } = params;
const skip = (perPage * page) - perPage;

const [data, total] = await this.repo.findAndCount({
    take,
    skip,
    // ...other options
});
```

Comment: used `findAndCount` its working!!